# Canales de Audio disponibles en AudioManager de Android

Tags: java, android, audio-manager

Estoy mirando los canales disponibles en Android que se obtienen del [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) tengo alguna duda para que sirven o que afectan

- AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC
- AudioManager.STREAM_RING
- AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM
- AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION
- AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL
- AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM
- AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF

¿Me pregunto el `STREAM_DTMF` a que están asociado o que es?
¿Al recibir una llamada, su volumen es `STREAM_SYSTEM`?
¿Durante una conversación telefónica su volumen es el `STREAM_VOICE_CALL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC** -> Hace referencia al sonido que emite cuando es alguna aplicación de reproducción de música/vídeo,etc
- **AudioManager.STREAM_RING** -> el volumen cuando te llaman
- **AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM** -> el volumen de alarma
- **AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION** -> el volumen de las notificaciones
- **AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL** -> el volumen mientras hablas por telefono
- **AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM** -> el volumen del sistema
- **AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF** -> el volumen de la marcacion por tonos, cada tecla tiene un tono diferente, existen reglas de conversión de tonos, de tal manera que solo enviando el tono se puede saber a que numero hace referencia.